# How do I associate two foreign keys to separate instances of the same parent model in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am working on a user to user 'Challenge' model in SQLAlchemy that needs to be linked to both the sending player, as well as the receiving player. I.e one user sends a challenge to another user, and users can see all of their sent challenges along with their received challenges. I initially attempted to solve this using an association table with no luck. I have since realized that an association table is unnecessary, however, I am unable to join the two tables as desired without receiving this error: `Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship User.sent_challenges - there are multiple foreign key paths linking the tables.`

I have read through the documentation and all similar problems that I could find through these forums but none seem to fix my problem. Below is the current implementation of my code. It is far from the only attempt I have made, however, I believe that it most accurately portrays what I am attempting to accomplish.

Challenge model:

```
class Challenge(db.Model):
__tablename__ = 'challenges'

id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

time = Column(Integer)
player_1_score = Column(Integer, nullable=True)
player_2_score = Column(Integer, nullable=True)

sender_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'), nullable=False)
receiver_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'), nullable=False)

sender = relationship("User", back_populates="sent_challenges")
receiver = relationship("User", back_populates="received_challenges")
```

User model:

```
class User(db.Model):
__tablename__ = 'users'

id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

user_name = Column(String(14), nullable=False)
level = Column(Integer)
high_score = Column(Integer)
points = Column(Integer)

sent_challenges = relationship("Challenge", back_populates="sender", cascade="all, delete")
received_challenges = relationship("Challenge", back_populates="receiver", cascade="all, delete")
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `foreign_keys` param so sqlalchemy knows which foreign key belongs to which relationship:

```py
sender = relationship("User", foreign_keys=[sender_id], back_populates="sent_challenges")
receiver = relationship("User", foreign_keys=[receiver_id], back_populates="received_challenges")
```

This is explained here with addresses that mirror your sender/receiver ambiguity:
[handling-multiple-join-paths](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/join_conditions.html#handling-multiple-join-paths)